# It is possible to program Linino to send HTTP requests and then use the returned values in sketch?

Tags: programming, library, sketch, arduino-yun, web

I am new to using Arduino Yun and I would like to know if it is possible to run a command from the Arduino sketch in order to make (probably, through the Bridge Library) Linino to execute a HTTP Request to a remote server. Then I would like to know if it is possible to use the returned values in that Arduino sketch.

In other words, I would like to delegate the task of retrieving values from the web to the Linux side and the usage of the retrieved data to the sketch.

If it is possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Bridge example](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Bridge) or [TemperatureWebPanel example](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TemperatureWebPanel): you see you can receive kind of "commands" and react "doing things".

Then take a look at [HTTP Client example](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HttpClient), where you delegate an HTTP call to the linux side.

Now mix the two: you can make HTTP calls after receiving a command from outside your Yun.

A short test can be done by cutting and pasting the examples above.